# Random binary matrix with two non-trivial constraints

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I need to generate a random matrix of `K` columns and `N` rows containing ones and zeroes, such that:

a) Each row contains exactly `k` ones.
b) Each row is different from the other (combinatorics imposes that if `N` > `nchoosek(K, k)` there will be `nchoosek(K,k)` rows).

Assume I want `N = 10000` (out of all the possible `nchoosek(K, k) = 27405` combinations), different 1×K vectors (with `K = 30`) containing k (with `k = 4`) ones and `K - k` zeroes.

This code:

```
clear all; close
N=10000; K=30; k=4;
M=randi([0 1],N,K);
plot(sum(M,2)) % condition a) not satisfied
```

does not satisfy neither a) nor b).

This code:

```
clear all; close;
N=10000;
NN=N;  K=30; k=4;
tempM=zeros(NN,K);   
for ii=1:NN
ttmodel=tempM(ii,:);
ttmodel(randsample(K,k,false))=1;  %satisfies condition a)
tempM(ii,:)=ttmodel;
end
Check=bi2de(tempM);                    %from binary to decimal
[tresh1,ind,tresh2] = unique(Check);%drop the vectors that appear more than once in the   matrix
M=tempM(ind,:);                             %and satisfies condition b)
plot(sum(M,2))                                  %verify that condition a) is satisfied
%Effective draws, Wanted draws, Number of possible combinations to draw from
[sum(sum(M,2)==k) N nchoosek(K,k) ]
```

satisfies condition a) and partially condition b). I say partially because unless NN>>N the final matrix will contain less than `N` rows each different from each other.

Is there a better and faster way (that possible avoids the for cycle and the need of having NN>>N) to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, generate *N* unique k-long permutations of the positions of ones:

```
cols = randperm(K, N);
cols = cols(:, 1:k);
```

Then generate the matching row indices:

```
rows = meshgrid(1:N, 1:k)';
```

and finally create the sparse matrix with:

```
A = sparse(rows, cols, 1, N, K);
```

To obtain the full form of the matrix, use `full(A)`.

#### Example

```
K = 10;
k = 4;
N = 5;

cols = randperm(K, N);
cols = cols(:, 1:k);
rows = meshgrid(1:N, 1:k)';
A = sparse(rows, cols , 1, N, K);
full(A)
```

The result I got is:

```
ans = 
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
    0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
    0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0
    0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
    1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

This computation should be pretty fast even for large values of *K* and *N*. For *K* = 30, *k* = 4, *N* = 10000 the result was obtained in less than 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Does this still hold in Matlab? From [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) it seems to me like `randperm(K,N)` will create a 1-by-N vector, not an N-by-K matrix which is what I think this answer relies on. Did The Mathworks change the behaviour of `randperm`?

Comment: Seems not to work in matlab2013b because when copying your example I get error: "Error using sparse
Vectors must be the same lengths."

Comment: @Dan good question. It's been a year since I've written this answer :) But I'll come up with something more "portable" :)

Comment: @EitanT It's very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547072/matlab-generating-a-matrix-with-random-elements/25547312#25547312 but mostly I'm just wondering if Mathworks changed the behaviour of `randperm`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use randperm(n) to generate random sequences of integers from 1 to n, and store the nonrepeated sequences as rows in a matrix M until size(unique(M,'rows'),1)==size(M,1). Then you could use M to index a logical matrix with the appropriate number of true values in each row.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory for nchoosek(K,k) integers, build an array of those, use a partial Fisher-Yates shuffle to get a proper uniformly random subset of N of those. Now, given the array of N integers, interpret each as the rank of the combination representing each row of your final array.  If you use colexicographical ordering of combinations, computing the combination from a rank is pretty simple (though it uses lots of binomial combination functions, so it pays to have a fast one).

I'm not a Matlab guy, but I've done things similar to this in C. This code, for example:

```
for (i = k; i >= 1; --i) {
    while ((b = binomial(n, i)) > r) --n;
    buf[i-1] = n;
    r -= b;
}
```

will fill the array `buf[]` with indices from `0` to `n-1` for the `r`th combination of `k` out of `n` elements in colex order. You would interpret these as the positions of the `1`s in your row.