# Matlab Generating a Matrix with random elements

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

How can I generate a Matrix with Boolean elements, but the sum of each row is equal to a certain constant number.

Comment: I think that you could try to generate a matrix of random elements. Then do a rowwise sort and set the largest n elements to true and the others to false. That would give each row a sum n.

Comment: @RTL similar question but the linked question doesn't have an accepted answer and this one is "easier" because you have no column specific restraint.

Comment: @Shai I don't know if this should be marked as a duplicate because the answer provided on that extremely similar question currently doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to have 20 columns (`n=20`) and your vector `a` contains the number of ones you want in each row:

```
n=20;
a= [5 6 1 9 4];
X= zeros(numel(a),n);
for k=1:numel(a)
    rand_order=randperm(n);
    row_entries=[ones(1,a(k)),zeros(1,n-a(k))];
    row_entries=row_entries(rand_order);
    X(k,:)=row_entries;
end
X=boolean(X);
```

What I do is generate me a random ordered index array `rand_order` then getting an array which contains the wanted number of ones filled with zero. Reorder those elements according to `rand_order` saving it and converting it to logical. And because of the use of a for loop `rand_order` is all the time computed again, so giving you different locations for your output:

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: one edit which you missed. place the conversion to boolean outside the loop. Otherwise you do it each time. Also check out the solution from Dan, which works without any loop (and is mostlikely faster for big matrices)

Answer (score 6):

Is each row the same one number?

```
k = 5;
m = 10;
n = 10;

[~, I] = sort(rand(m,n), 2)    
M = I <= k
```

If you don't want the same number of `1`s in each row, but rather have a vector that specifies per row how many `1`s you want then you need to use `bsxfun` as well:

```
K = (1:10)';                        %//'
m = 10;
n = 10;

[~, I] = sort(rand(m,n), 2)    
M = bsxfun(@ge, K,I)
```

Comment: Great solution. This problem seemed hard to vectorize